# is there a way that I can undo a git push which is not the last

Tags: git

my git commit order as below:

```
commit A ==> commit B(merge master) ==> commit C ==> commit D
```

the commit **B** used to pull and merge master, and after that commit **C** and **D** used to add/change file. Every commit has been push remote.

However when commit **D** push remote, the **master rollback **. Then my branch has some code which get from commit B(merge master) and the current master dont have for it has been rollback.

In order to keep consistent with master, I pull and merge master again but make  no effect. 
So is there a way I can remove commit B(merge master)? after that the commit flow look as:

```
commit A ==> commit C ==> commit D.
```

Every advice will be great appreciate.

Comment: do u have to revert the  previous commit ?

Comment: @MonisMajeed I expect to reserve commit A,C,D. and remove B

Comment: read here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the branch and its merge commit are already pushed to the remote and are public, we should be cautious and avoid rewriting the history of this branch.  A safe option would be to revert the merge commit B:

```
git checkout your_branch
git revert -m 1 <SHA-1 hash of B>
```

This assumes that you want to follow the first parent of the merge.  If not, then use `-m 2` instead.  You may check `git log` to verify that the first parent follows back into commit A.

Note that this solution will make a new commit on top of your branch.  To push these changes, a normal push will suffice:

```
git push origin your_branch
```

Comment: then will my commit C and D lost?

Comment: Not at all.  As mentioned, this option just functionally removes the merge commit B.